# Terrain Texture is blurry in unityplayer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in unityplayer the terrain texture is blurry (image 1).

I tried changing the  Quality settings and the import settings of the texture.

At the second image you can see how it should look like, and how it does look like in unity editor.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

I created a new terrain in the editor and made all the changes i want to make to this terrain. Than it works, but it doesn't work with a terrain that is created by script only.